# Is it possible to Scan nearby Bluetooth low energy(BLE) devices without turning on Bluetooth on mobile phone?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to build location based advertising application in which I want to JUST read the mac addresses of nearby BLE beacons and not connect to those devices while having my Bluetooth off on mobile(either Android or iOS). I wanted to know if it is possible?

I made a flutter application and scanning nearby BLE devices using flutter blue plus package. Is there any other package which can be used to just scan nearby devices without turning the Bluetooth on? Or is there any type of permission which allows me to do this?

Comment: How do you expect to scan for Bluetooth devices if Bluetooth is turned off?  That's like expecting to drive somewhere in your car without starting it

Comment: Also, on iOS you cannot get the MAC address of Bluetooth devices.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452971/bluetooth-scanning-works-without-bluetooth-turned-on-android?rq=1